# Google Storage delete Object in c#

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using Google Storage API v1 in my C# Web App.

Deleting files doesn't work, nothing happens, I get no error or exception.

```
 Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object fileobj = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object()
       {
            Name = path  // "folder 1/somefile.txt"
       };

var res =  service.Objects.Delete(bucketName, fileobj.Name).Execute();
```

Writing files works:

```
Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object fileobj = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object()
        {
            Name = path // "folder 1/somefile.txt"  
        };

        var localPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + path);

        using (var streamOut = new FileStream(localPath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var res = await service.Objects.Insert(fileobj, bucketName, streamOut, "binary/octet-stream").UploadAsync(); // content-type=binary/octet-stream ist default
        }
```

Comment: What is the exception you are getting when you delete?

Comment: as I mentioned I get no exception.

Comment: so what is the conent of "res", is it stuck or do you get a reply back?

Comment: So it's stuck. I think it's related to this one: https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/606 (for now you can downgrade to 1.9.2 for all Google.Apis packages, 1.10 is coming up soon...)